# Basic working of getter setter when they are called

Tags: getter-setter

If we are Sending a [GET] Request to API then then as per my understanding setter will be called and it will set the value of the respective data members.

Will Get be also called here or what is the working ?

If we are sending a [POST[ request to API then as per my understanding the getter will be called and the data members data will be send to the API as per getter.

Will Set also be called here or what is the working?

In case of Get Request refer below class getter setter:

```
public class Car
{
    private string _speed;

    public string Speed
    {
        get { return _speed; }
        set {
                if (value >= 0 && value <= 100)
                {
                    _speed = value;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Will Get be also called here?

In case of [POST] Request refer below code of getter setter

```
public class Student
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name.toUpperCase(); }
        set {
                    _name = value;
              }
    }
}
```

Will Set also be called here?

Please help me understand this basic concept.

Comment: Student.Name = newValue <- setter gets called ... print(Student.Name) <- getter gets called

Comment: okay. what about API Requests

Comment: you free to design -  so basically your request contains a `method: 'GET' | 'POST' | '...' - and you are free to ignore this - so your code will not be create by the intent of a possible POST - it will be designed -by you, a framework, etc... and unless you tell us what is happening behind the scenes ...

Comment: Hi I still am confused about basic flow: as per my question example, i have get and set both in class defined . Now I send a API GET Request so what is supposed to be called by default. Please explain with some code if possible for you

Comment: nothing - you have two classes in the dark - if i send an get request to google nothing will hapen with your classes - pls shed some light and show us your api (scope - what is using/ accessing those classes)

Comment: Okay , Got it now ... thanks... the answer was in your first response